# Is the grammars in Java7 spec really equivalent?

Tags: java, java-7, grammar, language-lawyer

The grammar in [chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) of JLS v7 seem to differ from the constructs elsewhere in the documentation, but to me there seem to be differences. Specifically in chapter 15 the rules are:

```
RelationalExpression:
  ShiftExpression
  RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression
  RelationalExpression > ShiftExpression
  RelationalExpression <= ShiftExpression
  RelationalExpression >= ShiftExpression
  RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
```

which makes `foo instanceof Bar` a RelationalExpression (and therefore an EqualityExpresson) which in turn can be used as LHS in the EqualityExpression rule which makes `foo instanceof Bar == false` an EqualityExpression.

But when looking at the grammar in chapter 18 they've simplified it a bit:

```
Expression2:
  Expression3 [Expression2Rest]

Expression2Rest:
  { InfixOp Expression3 }
  instanceof Type
```

Which looks odd, which means that we can chain together `Expression3`s with binary operators OR we can check the type of one `Expression3`. Specifically now `foo instanceof Bar` is an `Expression2`, but I don't see that it would be valid to use an `Expression2` as LHS of an equality comparision.

Have I missed something in the grammar of chapter 18 that makes `foo instanceof Bar == false` a valid expression? Note that it is a valid expression according to the rules in chapter 15 and according to my compiler.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the spec to me.  Note that the [equivalent section of the Java 8 spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html) uses the same grammar as chapter 15.

Comment: Why would it be a problem that `foo instanceof Bar == false` is a valid expression? I just checked it and the compiler accepts it.

Comment: @Clashsoft Not a problem, except that according to the later grammar it isn't: `foo instanceof Bar` is an `Expression2` and in that, but the LHS of `x == y` should be an `Expression3`. Unless of course I've missed something - which (what I've missed) would be an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question deserves a good answer, so let's take a good close look.

Based solely on the grammar in Chapter 18:

Anything with an *InfixOp* (e.g. `==`) either fits *Expression2Rest* or fits nothing. And *Expression2Rest* only belongs inside *Expression2*. So, if `foo instanceof Bar == false` is legal Java, that means that `foo instanceof Bar` has to be an *Expression3*.

> *Expression2 :*
>   *Expression3 [Expression2Rest]*
>
> *Expression2Rest:*
>   *{InfixOp Expression3}*
>   **instanceof** *Type*

But `foo instanceof Bar` is not an *Expression3*. There's no *PrefixOp* and no cast, so to be an *Expression3* it would have to be a *Primary*. But it just doesn't fit.

> *Expression3:*
>   *PrefixOp Expression3*
>   **(** *(Expression* | *Type)* **)** *Expression3*
>   *Primary { Selector } { PostfixOp }*
>
> *Primary:*
>   *Literal*
>   *ParExpression*
>   **this** *[Arguments]*
>   **super** *SuperSuffix*
>   **new** *Creator*
>   *NonWildcardTypeArguments (ExplicitGenericInvocationSuffix* | **this**
>   *Arguments)*
>   *Identifier {* . *Identifier } [IdentifierSuffix]*
>   *BasicType {* **[]** }* **.class**
>   **void.class**

Conclusion: based solely on the grammar presented in Chapter 18, `foo instanceof Bar == false` is not a legal Java expression. !?!?!

Of course that's nonsense. `foo instanceof Bar` yields a boolean result, and that result can certainly be compared to `false`. The expression compiles and runs.

Better conclusion: Chapter 18 isn't authoritative, but the rest of the book is.

Section 2.3 states that

> A *syntactic grammar* for the Java programming language is given in Chapters 4, 6-10, 14, and 15. ... Chapter 18 also gives a syntactic grammar for the Java programming language, better suited to implementation than exposition.

By the grammar rules presented in Chapter 15, `foo instanceof Bar == false` **is** a legal Java expression. But check out the last sentence before section 15.20.1: "The type of a relational expression is always **boolean**." That directly conflicts with the *RelationalExpression* rules themselves in 15.20. (In particular, it implies that the LHS of `instanceof` must evaluate to **boolean**.) It can't possibly be true.

Bestest conclusion: This book has issues. If you want to know whether something is legal Java, you have to compile and run it, preferably on Oracle's reference implementation. And even then there might be bugs. It is, after all, just software.

And I think that if they changed the *Expression2* rule just a little bit, Chapter 18 could be right. Like so:

> *Expression2 :
>   *Expression3 [* **instanceof** *Type ]*
>   *Expression2 {InfixOp Expression3}*

But who knows, that might cause other problems. In any case, it's fixed in Java 8.